# DataValidation List Comparing if its the same or not?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and I would like to know how can I compare two validation lists (if they have the same source) in order to achieve what I need.   (See Screenshot to help you understand what is the problem)

Problem: I have a column B (for example) and when I copy/paste one cell from that column B to another row in that column I want to check if the validation list source its the same where its getting pasted in order to "Allow if its the same" or to " Error to undo if they are different".

I dont know how can i compare the point source of validation list, i cant understand it very well if someane could help i would apreacite. This is a sample code that i know its gonna be something like that but dont know how to do it.

```
Dim Name As String
Name = target.Value
With Range("B" & target.Row)
    With .Validation                    
        .Modify xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, "=" & Name
    End With
End With
```

All expected results are in that screenshots to be more easy to understand what is the main point here:

https://prnt.sc/no5pi6

Answer (score 0):

If you have a cell, A1 for example, which has a list-type data validation rule assigned to it, you can get the address of the validation list or the corresponding name of the named range like so:

```
Sub checkValidation()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your Worksheet")
Debug.Print sht.Range("A1").Validation.Formula1

End Sub
```

So, if for example the validation list is located in `sht.Range("S1:S5")`, you would get this printed in your immediate window:

```
=$S$1:$S$5
```

If the validation list is a named range, for example `ValidationList`, you would get:

```
=ValidationList
```

These are nothing more than just strings.

In that sense, you could compare the validation lists of two cells like so:

```
Sub checkValidationSource()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your Worksheet")
If sht.Range("A1").Validation.Formula1 = sht.Range("B1").Validation.Formula1 Then
'
'
'Do something
'
'
End If
End Sub
```